# Make php.ini file recursive on 1and1 hosting

Tags: .htaccess, settings, php

I have my website hosted on 1and1 servers and I want to adjust some settings in a php.ini file. I can create the file and it is being interpreted correctly but only for the immediate directory not for any subdirectories. I would like to not have to copy the php.ini file into every single subdirectory. The only way I have seen to do this from googling is to add the following to the .htaccess file

```
suPHP_ConfigPath /path/to/htdocs/php.ini
```

I have an .htaccess file and the different directives I have in there are being interpreted correctly but when I add that line it causes a 500 Internal Server error.

Can anyone suggest what I can do so that the php.ini settings are used in all the subdirectories without having to duplicate the php.ini file into all the subdirectories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create soft links in each folder to your main php.ini.  1and1 disallows many directives in their .htaccess files.  1and1's [support site has more information](http://faq.1and1.com/scripting_languages_supported/php/8.html).

Comment: this is a good solution so I don't have to make changes to all the different php.ini files but I would still have to create the linked files.

Comment: That's true, but how many directories do you have?  If you're using a PHP framework like Drupal, all of the work is started by the root index.php.  I think if you place the php.ini in the root folder, then you're covered.

Answer (score 0):

The suPHP is evaluated in a .htaccess PerDir context.  If you want to have different ini files for different directories then you need to use a separate .htaccess in each relevant directory.  By default Apache will use the lowest .htaccess on the request URI's path that it can find.  Alternatively if you have a systematic naming convention for the filenames, then you ban place the different suPHP directives in different  directives.